# I’m having issues booting up- frozen screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, msi

I’m having issues booting up. I have a work around (`hit shift on startup -->recovery mode-->recovery menu--> clean`, then resume normal boot) but it is annoying, to say the least.

Does anyone have any idea what might be the solution?

I’m running Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS on a MSI Stealth 15M laptop which has a 12th gen i7-1280P and an Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060 GPU which seems to be a bit of a hassle!

This screen is what I get frozen at if I don’t do the work around as mentioned:

[image: frozen at startup]